# How to access value from Firebase Realtime Database in React-native? (android)

Tags: android, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

On the left my database schema, on the right is my react-native code.

I followed [this](https://rnfirebase.io/database/usage) documentation to get started with Realtime Database for Android.

I am trying to get the value "Lesson" from key "Category".
none of the commands I tried work. How I can get Lesson value?
I tried test.parent but I got the correct location in my database but I want the values.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Documentation is your Friend!**

The answer to your question is in the document you attached!
If you scroll a bit down there's a section [One-time read](https://rnfirebase.io/database/usage#one-time-read)

To read the value once, call the once method on a reference:

```
import database from '@react-native-firebase/database';

database()
  .ref('/users/123')
  .once('value')
  .then(snapshot => {
    console.log('User data: ', snapshot.val());
  });
```

So just replace the ref path `'/users/123'` with your path `'Lesson 1/1 Introduction/Category'`

You can also listen for changes in the document in real-time. Check out [Real-Time Changes](https://rnfirebase.io/database/usage#realtime-changes)

```
import database from '@react-native-firebase/database';

database()
  .ref('/users/123')
  .on('value', snapshot => {
    console.log('User data: ', snapshot.val());
  });
```

Comment: is there a simpler approach that doesn't involve the snapshot methods?

Comment: I want to try and save the value '1 Introduction' and all of the other children that might be on the same level into an array

Comment: What do you mean by "simpler approach" ? Since you need all objects on the `1 Introduction` level, you should set the ref path as `Level 1`.  If you want to read from the DB only 1 time, then use the first method, when promise resolves, set it onto any state variable

Comment: Thanks
I was able to get what I needed like follows:

`    const reference = database()
    .ref()
    .once('value')
    .then(snapshot => {
      //get Levels from db
      let values = [];
      snapshot.forEach((child) => {
          values.push(child.key);
      })
      console.log(values);`